# Starting a server on command line vs. starting a server inside application

Tags: c++, qt, http, server, get

When I start a server on command line there is no problem communicating with it:

```
>powershell -Command "Start-Process '.\agent.exe' -Verb runAs"
```

[image: Launch server by command line]

---

However, starting a server inside C++/Qt application, the server reply is *not* as expected:

```cpp
QString agentName = "/agent.exe";
QString agentPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + agentName;
QStringList args = QStringList();
args = QStringList({"-Command", QString("Start-Process %1 -Verb runAs").arg(agentPath)});
m_agent->start("powershell", args);
```

[image: Launch server inside application]

This issue has bogged me down for a while. Looking for any hint to resolve it.

Comment: No images of text, please.

Comment: @DavisHerring Added code text =)

Comment: Unrelated: *powershell -Command "Start-Process '.\agent.exe' -Verb runAs"* Good God. What happened to *> agent.exe*? Shouldn't we be making computers easier to use?

Comment: @user4581301 It is still possible to run `>agent.exe`, however it won't run with **admin privileges** =(

Comment: Shows you how lazy I am. I run the terminal emulator as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3** with Qt 5.12.6 when this issue occurred.

I installed **Visual Studio Community 2017** and used it with Qt, then the issue got resolved. Not sure why, probably due to some upstream bug fixes?

Answer (score 0):

### Investigating Windows Defender Firewall

Just thought this might be the cause:

- Starting the server on command line, Windows Defender Firewall **allows** network access
- Starting the server inside C++/Qt application, firewall **prevents** network access

But, this test shows the Windows Defender Firewall might **not** be the cause:

[image: Firewall test]